# Why does flex item get stretched iOS 13?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, iphone, browser

[Here is the complete code on codepen](https://codepen.io/archieyang/pen/oNwgVNw)

```
    .Card {
      max-width: 20%;
      max-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
   .Cards {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-around;
   }
```

The view looks good on all devices except iOS 13, which looks like the cards are stretched.
[Stretched on iOS 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7dej.jpg)

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

The max-width and max-height properties of CSS works better, but they are not supported in many browsers.

Try using `object-fit` property for the images.

Comment: max-width is well [supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=max-height)

Answer (score 0):

I recognise that iOS 13 is no longer a serious concern given iOS 15 has now been released, but for the record this issue can be resolved by setting `align-items: start;` on your `.Cards` container:

[image: iOS Simulator running iOS 13.7 demonstrating the fix working as designed]